# Can you name of this text editor?

Tags: text, editor

[Please name this text editor?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7dyY.png)

i need this text editor name can any one name this text editor?

[Editor Picture Link ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7dyY.png)

Answer (score 0):

The WYSIWYG in the picture is TinyMCE.

Comment: Yeah thanks , Will it support indian ruppee Currency Symbol